# Center an img taking into account the img height

Tags: html, css, layout

Is it possible to center an image in a div, taking into account the height of the image.

HTML

```
<div class="holder">
    <h3>Article 1</h3>
    <div class="tl">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/144x70"/>
    </div>
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <div class="foot">
        <h4>Author</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="holder">
    <h3>Article 2</h3>
    <div class="tl">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/144x50"/>
    </div>
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <div class="foot">
        <h4>Author</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="holder">
    <h3>Article 3</h3>
    <div class="tl">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x15"/>
    </div>
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <div class="foot">
        <h4>Author</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.holder {
    width: 144px;
    height: 215px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 10px 50px 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}

h3 {
    margin: 4px 0 20px 0;
}

h4, p{
    margin: 0;
}

h3, h4, p {
    text-align: center;
}

.tl {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 12%;
    transform: translateY(-12%);
}

p {
    padding: 0 3px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.foot {
    width: 144px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 197px;
}
```

I have made a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/abn94Ldo/1/

I would like the centre point of all the images to line up so the text in each img placeholder (144x70 etc) is in line.

[image: example]

Comment: I have provided two options. Use either of them. Let me know if need any clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by two methods [by the way remove the top value for .tl div],

1. Make img `position:absolute` and set all the sides to 0 and `margin:auto`.

   ```
   img{
       position:absolute;
       top: 0px;
       left: 0px;
       right: 0px;
       bottom: 0px;
       margin:auto;
   }
   ```

Refer to [jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/abn94Ldo/2/)

2. To make the tl as `display:table`; and add a child with `display:table-row` and another inside with `display:table-cell`; Now you will be able to make the image position center by using `vertical-align: middle`;

Refer to [jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/abn94Ldo/4/)

Answer (score 2):

I would use a transform :

```
img {
position: relative;
top: 50%; // vertical placement according to preference
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/draquL3p/

Both absolute positioning and a table layout seem a bit hacky (although commonly used). My own choice would be to use them only when legacy browser support is required.

Answer (score 0):

Using positioning aligning image in middle. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/abn94Ldo/7/)

```
.tl img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/abn94Ldo/3/

```
.tl {
       vertical-align: middle;
       display: table-cell;
       text-align: center;
       margin-bottom: 30px;
       height: 70px;
       position: relative;
       top: 12%;
       transform: translateY(-12%);
       width: 144px;
       margin: 0 auto;
}
```